# How to INTERSECT tables for differences?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

EDIT: added table descrptions.

I have two tables. A temp table [tvwBundle] that accumulates information entered by the user and then a main table [tblBundle] that the temp table populates. I want the query to only list the differences between the two table and have only found ways to query the similarities.

Both table have the same fields.
WorkOrder, BundleNbr, BundleLtr, Clk, Shift, Step, (multiple) Dimensions, Complete, ActivityID

My form is designed to split Bundles into child bundles for various purposes. Once split, BundleLtr gets populated with our lettering scheme. I have a query:
`Me.cmbBundleToSplit.RowSource = "SELECT BundleNbr & BundleLtr AS Bundle FROM tblBundle GROUP BY BundleNbr & BundleLtr, [WO], [Complete], BundleNbr, BundleLtr HAVING [WO] = '" & Nz(Me.cmbShopOrder, "") & "' AND [Complete] <> False "ORDER BY BundleNbr, BundleLtr;"`

For my WorkOrder there are 8 bundles that populate into the combobox: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. Once an order has been split, it gets held in the tempTable until the user is ready to post it.

In the case a user would split multiple bundles: Once Bundle 1 gets split, I would like the BundleNbr 1 removed from the rowsource. I do this via: `result = fncMsgBox("Split another Bundle?", vbYesNo, "Split More?") If result = vbNo Then DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name End If`

if the user clicks 'yes' I would like to reset the rowsource.
So the RowSource would be: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
Once Bundle 2 gets split the new RowSource would be: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
When the RowSource = "" I would have `MsgBox "all Bundles are split"`

Currently I am playing with different options I can find in the query designer but am intending to put this into vba, I have not attempted the vba code since I cannot get the query to work. If you want to go the extra mile, I would really appreciate what this would look like in vba as well.

I have tried:

```
SELECT tblBundle.BundleNbr & tblBundle.BundleLtr AS Bundle, tblBundle.Step
FROM tblBundle
WHERE tblBundle.WO="WorkOrder" AND tblBundle.Step=200
UNION
SELECT tvwBundle.BundleNbr & tvwBundle.BundleLtr as Bundle, tvwBundle.Step
FROM tvwBundle 
WHERE tvwBundle.WO="WorkOrder" AND tvwBundle.Step=200;

SELECT DISTINCT tblBundle.*
FROM tblBundle
INNER JOIN tvwBundle ON tvwBundle.BundleNbr = tblBundle.BundleNbr WHERE tblBundle.WO = 
"WorkOrder" AND tblBundle.Step = 200

SELECT DISTINCT tblBundle.*
FROM tblBundle
Left JOIN tvwBundle ON tvwBundle.BundleNbr = tblBundle.BundleNbr WHERE tblBundle.WO = "WorkOrder" AND tblBundle.Step = 200

SELECT DISTINCT tblBundle.*
FROM tblBundle
Left OUTER JOIN tvwBundle ON tvwBundle.BundleNbr = tblBundle.BundleNbr WHERE tblBundle.WO = 
"WorkOrder" AND tblBundle.Step = 200
```

The 'RIGHT JOIN' didn't do it either.

EDIT:
The goal is to use the results of the query as a RowSource for a combobox. After 1 bundle is split, it is posted to the tempTable; which collects all split bundles that data is being entered on.

If the BundleNbr&BundleLtr combo is in tempTable or has a > step in the main table, do not list the Bundle.

### last step complete is 190
Entering data for step 200

tblBundle

| WO | Step | BundleNbr | BundleLtr | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | 190 | 1 | "" | 30 |
| string | 190 | 2 | "" | 30 |
| string | 190 | 3 | "" | 30 |
| string | 190 | 4 | "" | 30 |

tvwBundle

| WO | Step | BundleNbr | BundleLtr | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "" | "" | "" | "" | "" |

^^RowSource = 1, 2, 3, 4^^

---

While Splitting Bundles:

tvwBundle

| WO | Step | BundleNbr | BundleLtr | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | 200 | 1 | "" | 10 |
| string | 200 | 1 | "a" | 10 |
| string | 200 | 1 | "b" | 10 |

tblBundle

| WO | Step | BundleNbr | BundleLtr | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | 190 | 1 | "" | 30 |
| string | 190 | 2 | "" | 30 |
| string | 190 | 3 | "" | 30 |
| string | 190 | 4 | "" | 30 |

^^RowSource = 2, 3, 4^^

---

While Splitting Bundle:

tvwBundle

| WO | Step | BundleNbr | BundleLtr | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | 200 | 1 | "" | 10 |
| string | 200 | 1 | "a" | 10 |
| string | 200 | 1 | "b" | 10 |
| string | 200 | 2 | "" | 10 |
| string | 200 | 2 | "a" | 10 |
| string | 200 | 2 | "b" | 10 |

tblBundle

| WO | Step | BundleNbr | BundleLtr | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | 190 | 1 | "" | 30 |
| string | 190 | 2 | "" | 30 |
| string | 190 | 3 | "" | 30 |
| string | 190 | 4 | "" | 30 |

^^RowSource = 3, 4^^

---

Then say the user doesn't get to the 2nd half until tomorrow.
They will post the data entry so the main table looks like:

tblBundle

| WO | Step | BundleNbr | BundleLtr | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| string | 200 | 1 | "" | 10 |
| string | 200 | 1 | "a" | 10 |
| string | 200 | 1 | "b" | 10 |
| string | 200 | 2 | "" | 10 |
| string | 200 | 2 | "a" | 10 |
| string | 200 | 2 | "b" | 10 |
| string | 190 | 1 | "" | 30 |
| string | 190 | 2 | "" | 30 |
| string | 190 | 3 | "" | 30 |
| string | 190 | 4 | "" | 30 |

tvwBundle

| WO | Step | BundleNbr | BundleLtr | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "" | "" | "" | "" | "" |

^^RowSource = 3, 4^^

### **I'm almost there with this:

```
intStep = 0
rst.Open "SELECT Step FROM tblBundle WHERE WO = '" & Me.cmbShopOrder & "' ORDER BY Step DESC;"

    If Not (rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then
        rst.MoveFirst
        
        Do Until intStep <> 0
            If rst!Step >= Me.cmbStep Then
                rst.MoveNext
            Else
                intStep = rst!Step
            End If
        Loop
    End If
rst.Close
Me.cmbBundleToSplit.RowSource = "SELECT tblBundle.BundleNbr & 
tblBundle.BundleLtr as Bundle FROM tblBundle LEFT JOIN tvwBundle ON 
tblBundle.[BundleNbr] = tvwBundle.[BundleNbr] WHERE tblBundle.WO = '" & 
Me.cmbShopOrder & "' AND tblBundle.Step = " & intStep & " AND 
tvwBundle.BundleNbr Is Null;"
```

Comment: Just a thought about database structure. It seems like you're trying to avoid orphaned records. I'm wondering if it would work to have the main table and a sub table that you could link via foreign key and that would contain the splits. The current setup seems to work around that type of structure. I might misunderstand what you're trying to do but a parent-child table and form arrangement, at least from what I'm seeing, seems like it would work better than a temp table to main table arrangement. Apologies if I’m off the mark.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access appears to not support minus, except or even a full outer join, so I'd recommend you to use left/right outer joins and filter the results

let's assume I have 2 tables

tab_1

| id | text_col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

tab_2

| id | text_col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | d |
| 4 | e |

So, the expected result would be

| text_col |
| --- |
| a |
| d |
| e |

It might be achieved by using this query

```
select tab_1.text_col
  from tab_1 
  left join tab_2 
    on tab_1.text_col = tab_2.text_col
 where tab_2.text_col is null -- together with left join this condition will show you lines that exists in tab_1 only
 union all
 select tab_2.text_col
   from tab_1
  right join tab_2 
     on tab_1.text_col = tab_2.text_col
  where tab_1.text_col is null -- together with right join this condition will show you lines that exists in tab_2 only
```

Comment: Working in the query designer still, In the where clause I need the work order to match otherwise I get the information for every order minus what is in table 2. I added `AND tab_2.WO = "WorkOrder" then the same but for tab_1 in the second `WHERE` clause and i get 0 results. Both tables have the exact same fields. Both tables will match on the WO but returns no results. There should be at least 7 results for this specific order I'm working with after information for 1 is put into tab_2

Comment: Hi @SamwiseVB can you perhaps update post with how your tables are defined, what data in there, and what yre you expecting to see?

Comment: The post has been updated with more information. I hope this makes my situation more clear!

Comment: @SamwiseVB sorry, I'm still not sure I am following you. It is better just to show example like "here is my table 1, here is my table 2 and here is the result I am expecting to see"

Comment: I added more information! I'm not sure what else to include unless you have a more specific question.

Comment: @SamwiseVB now I get it. You started it with an SQL-related question on how to find intersection of two tables. But now it is going to the VBA side with data source population which I don't know much of. Sorry I can't help here

Comment: Thanks for your help! Its difficult phrasing for me because I'm not familiar with SQL. How did you format the tables? I was looking for it and couldn't find it

Comment: @SamwiseVB it's here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  . Just scroll down to tables section

Answer (score 0):

Use a merge statement.  This is a typical basic ETL process (Extract, Transform, Load).  Except in your case, you don't seem to be doing a lot of Transforming.

I assume you're using MSSQL.  Also, you may want to research Slowly Changing Dimensions.  The change you are looking for here is SCD1, where the change history is not preserved, and the matching entry is overwritten when changed.   Things get fun when you want to preserve the change history (that's SCD2)

See:

[MERGE (Transact-SQL) - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Basic sql-server-merge](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-merge/)

You've asked for query, however the merge will write to your main table.

It would be something like this...

```
MERGE tblBundle target USING tvwBundle source
ON 

-- use a normal join condition here, where the matching keys exist. 
-- Looks like you've got a Work Order column 
-- I've completely guessed your keys from the info above
tblBundle.WO = tvwBundle.WO AND 
tblBundle.Step = tvwBundle.Step AND 
tvwBundle.BundleNbr = tblBundle.BundleNbr

WHEN MATCHED
    THEN 
-- Your update_statement here, updating the main table
-- Use the source and target aliases specified in the initial MERGE line

WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN 
-- Your insert_statement here 
-- Again, use the source and target aliases specified in the initial MERGE line


-- optionally, delete rows in target that don't exist in source, 
-- I don't think you want this. 
-- WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
--     THEN DELETE;
```

The sqlserver central link above describes the actual merge statement well.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I am reading through the literature and it seems that this only works for updating/deleting records from the main table. The goal is not to update the main table, but update a combobox.RowSource removing the bundle that has information in the temp table from the dropdown. So my original query populates all bundles that were completed on the last step. The temp table is built while entering information for the current step. I want to remove the bundle from the rowsource that has information in the temp table so the user cannot double enter data for the same bundle